# How to get a British passport stamp?

Tags: uk, passports, passport-stamps

I'm going to the UK tomorrow and I've only been there twice before. I'm a British citizen and they always refuse to stamp me, is there any way that I can get them to give me a passport stamp? Is there anything saying that they have to stamp me if I request it? I also have a German passport, could I maybe get a stamp if I used that?

Comment: Could you clarify why you want a stamp?

Comment: One time I needed a stamp from my home country to prove that I had returned home on a certain date. Immigration wouldn't do it (for the same reason as you), but Customs had no problem doing so.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why they would put an entry stamp on a citizen's passport - you can come and go as you please, esp. within the EU. Using your German passport could be a problem - most dual-nationality countries require you to use their passport and not the other one(s).

Asia on the other hand is stamp-happy. My Japanese wife's passport has more in-out stamps from Japan than I have from all countries combined.

If someone needs proof of arrival/departure show them a copy of the boarding pass. Note that as a UK citizen you would have very, very few valid reasons to prove you landed in the UK on a certain date. However, if we turn the question around there are many reasons why you would need to prove you *departed* another country on a certain date. In that case an exit stamp would be better.

Comment: I am a British subject and travel on a Canadian passport. They stamp it, of course. Your first sentence should say "British passport" not "citizen's passport" since my Canadian passport is a citizen's passport. Also the UK doesn't require you to travel on a British passport. I know some countries do, but they don't. (Also I expect the stamp is not for proof of anything but as a souvenir or keepsake.)